# How to reference a file from a pre-request script or a test script in Postman?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, postman, postman-pre-request-script

**Problem Description:**
I have a file containing json schema. I want to use the schema to validate multiple collections in Postman. I want to be able to reference this file from a pre-request script or test-script.

**What I've tried so far:**

- **Globals/Data file:** I have tried defining the schema as a globals file
  and importing that file at run-time. Using Newman command line, that involves modifying the run query. *The test-automation criteria does not allow me to modify the run queries.*
- **Separate collection**: The schema could be separated into it's own collection and mentioned in a pre-request script to set global variable. The global variable can be used across all collections. The problem with this approach is a dummy request is needed to run the pre-request script.
- **File**: Hence, I thought of putting schema in a file and see if there's a way to reference that from pre-request script.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is ridiculously necro and you may not remember, but did you ever figure out a solution or workaround?

Comment: I ended up not using JSON schema since for my requirement digging deep into this was not worth it. But I just checked for any updates on Postman, and they've included the functionality to validate schema. 
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/design-and-develop-apis/the-api-workflow/#editing-your-schema
Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately my purpose is different, but thanks for the response. :) I was hoping you had figured out how to read in the file.